# How to pass action while sending message using IBM watson Assistant V2

Tags: python, watson-assistant

I have configured WatsonX assistant Lite and added some actions.
Using Python SDK or using CURL command, I am trying to send message  using action and expect response but i am unable to find any proper documentation  about how i can pass the action id in body of the Curl or python call. Can anyone point me to example.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider sharing your code

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to invoke a specific action, watsonx Assistant knows based on the user utterance to choose the right action. Just make sure you provided enough examples when you created your action.